# Dynamic Python Unit Test

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am new to python unit testing. I have been playing with unittest and py.test. I want to validate data in that is ini format. An example

```
[Section1]
key1 = value1
key2 = value2
key3 = value3
...
[Section2]
key1 = value1
...
```

The section names could be different in the ini file. I have data and I compare it to the section/keynames.

I'm trying to create a test case for each section so I can generate a report with failures by section name and which key/value is wrong. I research by I am totally stuck.

Comment: I don't understand what this has to do with unit testing. This appears to be about actual program functionality.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: I'm using python 3.5. I am trying to validate my configuration data against a golden copy. I am not sure if the unit test is the correct term. I figure I can use unittest framework to generate test results.

Answer (score 1):

Where gold.cfg is:

> [Section1]
>   key1 = value1
>   key2 = value2
>   key3 = value3
>   
>   [Section2]
>   key4 = value4
>   key5 = value5
>   key6 = value6
>   
>   [Section3]
>   key7 = value7
>   key8 = value8
>   key9 = value9

And where example.cfg is:

> [Section1]
>   key1 = value1
>   key2 = value2
>   key3 = value3
>   
>   [Section2]
>   key1 = value1

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import unittest

try:
    import ConfigParser as configparser  # Python 2
except ImportError:
    import configparser  # Python 3


class TestValidConfig(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.gold_config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
        self.gold_config.read('gold.cfg')
        self.allowed_section_names = self.gold_config.sections()
        return None

    def _test_allowed_section_names_pass(self):
        example_config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
        example_config.read('example.cfg')
        for section_name in example_config.sections():
            self.assertTrue(section_name in self.allowed_section_names)
        return None

    def test_values_by_section_pass(self):
        """Test example using setUp()"""
        example_config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
        example_config.read('example.cfg')

        for section_name in example_config.sections():
            example_pairs = example_config.items(section_name)
            gold_pairs = self.gold_config.items(section_name)
            self.assertTrue(set(example_pairs).issubset(set(gold_pairs)))
        return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Iterate over the section named with the sections() method: `for section_name in example_config.sections()`.

The items() method returns a list of key, value tuples, so use set to assert that the list of key, value pairs from the example file is a [subset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset) of the key, value pairs from your gold copy.

(If the gold copy has a single section listed all allowed key/value pairs, modify the code so that section name is used explicitly  during the comparison.)

Comment: Awesome thanks for the input. What if the section names are unknown? I was trying to figure out how to create test functions on the fly based on section names which are unknown until runtime.

Comment: @Danny The RawConfigParser class has a sections() method that returns a list of all the section names. So for 'config' or 'self.config' if you're referencing the object from setUp() just use `sections_list = config.sections()`

Comment: okay make sense to get the list of sections with `config.sections` call. In the above code you have specific test functions an example `test_section_one_keys_pass`. How do I create these functions on the fly based from list of sections?

Comment: So the section names can be anything, but the key/value pairs are known? Are they always in the same order? You can add a step to iterate `for section in config.sections(): #test if config.items(section) is in a set of valid results` depending on the situation. But you mentioned having a gold copy of the file, so I need some clarification.

Comment: The golden copy is another an another ini file that contains all possible sections and key/value pairs. The target ini file is a subset of the golden copy. I wanted to test to make sure it is a valid configuration file against golden copy. I was trying to use one of the python test frameworks for these and generate a nice test report of which sections pass/fail.

Comment: I rewrote the answer based on your feedback. In short, just use `.issubset()` from set to assert that the provided key/value pairs are an allowed subset of the golden copy, for each section in `example_config.sections()`.